# ng-model is not storing data on nested ng-repeat on 2d array

Tags: html, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I'm using nested ng-repeat on an 2d array and I've used ng-model on third ng-repeat but my ng-model is not storing the data in the object.

**JavaScript Code**

```
emrService
 .getData("checkJson",id)
    .then(function(data){
        if(data.success){
         if(data.data != ""){
            $scope.jSONCheck1 = JSON.parse(data.data);
             $scope.tableData = [];
             for(var k=0;k<$scope.jSONCheck1.length;k++){
             var twoD = [];
             var cols = $scope.jSONCheck1[k].columns;
             twoD.push(cols);
             for(var i=0;i<$scope.jSONCheck1[k].rows.length;i++){
             var row = [];
             row.push($scope.jSONCheck1[k].rows[i]);
             // remaining ans empty values
             for(var j = 0;j<cols.length-1;j++){
                row.push("");
             }
             twoD.push(row);
            }
            $scope.tableData.push(twoD);
            }
            }else{
                $scope.jSONCheck = [];
            }
            if($scope.jSONCheck.length != 0)
             console.log($scope.jSONCheck);
            }
            });
            }
```

**HTML Code**

```
<table ng-repeat="table in tableData" class="col-lg-12 sections ng-scope" 
 style="width:100%; border: solid; border-width: 0.1px;">
 <tr ng-repeat="list in table track by $index">
 <td style="border: solid; border-width: 0.1px; padding: 5.4px;" ng- 
  repeat="c_list in list track by $index">
  <input style="width:100%;" type="text" ng-model="list.c_list[$index]" ng-
   hide="(table.indexOf(list) == 0) || (list.indexOf(c_list) == 0)"/>
  <strong><span ng-if="(table.indexOf(list) == 0) || (list.indexOf(c_list) 
   == 0)" ng-bind="c_list"></span></strong>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: add `$scope.tableData` result as `json` in your question

Comment: @Ahmad: there are 3 `ng-repeat` and all creates `new child scope`, So no.of `parent ng-repeat` you have, just add similar no. of  `$parent`, basically to access firstArray index, from 3rdng-repeat, do : `$parent.$parent.$index`

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of parent ng-repeat you have to pass index like as $parent.$index

Html Code

```
<table ng-repeat="table in tableData" class="col-lg-12 sections ng-scope" style="width:100%; border: solid; border-width: 0.1px;">
    <tr ng-repeat="list in table track by $index">
        <td style="border: solid; border-width: 0.1px; padding: 5.4px;" ng- repeat="c_list in list track by $index">
            <input style="width:100%;" type="text" ng-model="list.c_list[$parent.$index]" ng- hide="(table.indexOf(list) == 0) || (list.indexOf(c_list) == 0)" />
            <strong><span ng-if="(table.indexOf(list) == 0) || (list.indexOf(c_list) 
   == 0)" ng-bind="c_list"></span></strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.